# does ASUS HS-W1 headset work on linux

Tags: usb, 15.04, headphones, headset

i would like to know if some one has the new ASUS HS-W1 Headphones and if yes do they work on Ubuntu, because I've tried to find everywhere but didn't find the answer

Comment: These use an *ad hoc* 2.4GHz wireless connection, much like many cordless mice. That will work fine on Ubuntu. **What you need to identify is whether Ubuntu recognise the USB device (vendor/device ID), and allows it to work as an audio headset (speakers, microphone).** *You either need to find out by attempting yourself, or hear from someone who has.*

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems that it works, so any one who wants to buy it can use it on Ubuntu